# codeigniter как сделать запрос в бд

Tags: codeigniter

есть таблица с записями и в каждой записи поле - acc, в нем хранится сериализованный массив с данными типа `'1','2','3','4','5'`
во второй записи - `'1','2','3','4'`

как сделать запрос на выборку записи, где есть значение '5'

Comment: можете более подробнее объяснить. вопрос не понятный

Comment: Вообще ответ зависит от используемой БД.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('5', acc) !=", 0)->get('thetable');
```